# HTMLElement prototype in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I wish to check if an argument passed to my function is an HTMLElement, using the instanceof operator. I know that this doesn't work in IE7, because AFAIK IE7 doesn't define HTMLElement. I figured: no problem, I'll just fall back to a parent prototype like Node. But, as answers on StackOverflow have learned me, the Node-object is also not defined in IE7

What now is the best way to test if my parameter is a node/HTMLElement? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Node interface `HTMLElement` corresponds to nodes of type 1.

```
const unsigned short      ELEMENT_NODE                   = 1;
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1841493061

Thus, you should check for the argument's `nodeType`:

```
if (arg && 1 === arg.nodeType) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used IE7 in ages, but I would check with a `if (typeof elementNode == 'element')`
It might be 'element' or 'HTMLElement'. To make sure first do an `alert(typeof elementNode);` to know what its type will be. So then you can compare against it.

**Edit:** first commenter clarified ↑ this should not work.

Then I would try checking if there is such a member like nodeType or nodeName.
Maybe with something like `if (elementNode.nodeName !== null)` just as example. Always try alert()ing before.

Comment: No, `typeof` with DOM elements returns `'object'` in IE7. And `.toString()` returns `'[object]'`.